# Asynchronous request-reply design in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-web

I'm building a web application using Flutter, and I have some requests that take a lot of time in server side, and "hold" http resources until the requests are answered.

To deal with this I read you can do polling or other solutions (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply)).

What is the correct design in flutter? How would you implement it in flutter?

Comment: There's no real easy way to do that.  Even though browsers have a turing-complete engine, it's really not suited to such tasks.  Instead move that to a server, and set up a REST interface to trigger it.

Comment: The requests take time in server side of course :)
But the client side has a few resources that are "taken" until the server answers. e.g chrome queues other http requests because it can have 6 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some requests that take a lot of time, and "hold" http
> resources until the requests are answered

Sounds like you are using a synchronous approach, where your program sits and wait until the responses comes back.  Instead, try using an asynchronous approach, that will allow your program to continue to run while you wait for the responses to come back.

I know nothing about Dart or Flutter, but these should help get you started:

- https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await
- https://medium.com/flutterdevs/exploring-asynchronous-programming-in-dart-flutter-25f341af32f

**Update in response to OP's comment**

If you have long-running tasks happening on the server, and you need to get the data back to a web-client then async HTTP requests are a legitimate architecture based on what you have explained so far.

If processing is blocked then maybe there's possibly an issue with you implementation.  Alternatively there might be issues between the browser and client (issues with a proxy server, etc), so check for those types of issues.

If you need another option altogether then websockets might be worth looking into.

Comment: I work asynchronously, my program continues to run, but still no more requests can be processed because of resources limit in the web browser.

Comment: How many requests are you making? What is the size of the expected response? Have you made the requests with postman to make sure there is nothing odd going on, on the server side? Show some code and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: @user693336 I make about 30 requests, which the server takes a few seconds to "handle" each one, and the response size is very small. It's OK that the server takes time as it's difficult calculations, and that's not the problem I'm trying to solve. 
The question is about architecture \ design - I have requests that take a lot of time in the server side, and the question is what architecture to use (clearly HTTP requests won't do).

Comment: Are your tasks such that pushing the data to the app would work? Also, is it possible to pre-calculate the data?

Comment: @YaaraZegelman - 'but still no more requests can be processed because of resources limit in the web browser' - what errors are you getting?  If it's only ~30 small requests then I don't see why the browser is having issues.  Without specific details on any errors we are totally in the dark.

Comment: @user693336
Again, the problem is not that the server takes a long time, that's OK. It's also clear that I need to have asynchronous approach in which the server can push data to the client when that data is ready. The question is HOW do I do asynchronous approach *in flutter*. Please see the link I attached in my question to understand this better.

Comment: @AdrianK
I don't get any errors, it's just that my requests are queued by the web browser for a long time until the first requests are answered... It's not 30 small requests, as I wrote, the server's processing time is very long so the HTTP request waits a long time for an answer. Please see the link I attached to understand this subject better.

Comment: If you've followed the code in the links, and by default, your requests are asynchronous. Perhaps what you need is to move your requests to another isolate. So that it can be processed while the UI thread continues to run. See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html, https://www.javatpoint.com/dart-isolates, https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a, and https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-spawn-kill-send-message-to-isolate.

Comment: Also, if your 30 requests are using up the system resources (on a pc this shouldn't be an issue, but on an embedded system it could be), why not queue the requests and make only a few requests at a time? This could greatly reduce the amount of system resources you are using,